# Why is the limit of this function $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+2} - \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right)$$

I keep working this limit out as infinity as each term separately works out at infinity or non-existent but online calculators and the book solution tell me the limit is $0$.

Can anyone help me understand the steps to generate the right hand limit?

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}}$, there's a very important difference!

Comment: We can probably give better help if you show us what you do when you get $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: it is the first one @AlphaNumeric

Comment: @Henrik I just checked and I don't get sqrt(2).  I get infinity so will edit the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}.$$ You get $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}$$ which tends to 0. (expanding in sight of binomial theorem is a pretty common trick)

Comment: we are looking for the limit as x tends to zero (right-hand side limit), so wouldn't the 1/x terms tend to infinity in your answer?

Comment: @JohnCurry Yes, ${1 \over x}$ tends to infinity, but it is in the denominator, so the whole fraction tends to 0.

Comment: @lisyarus Ah, ok, I think I am rather rusty at this.  So it's ok to generate the infinities on the denominator as it works out at 1/infinity which is zero.  So it is a valid limit.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @lisyarus

Comment: @JohnCurry Problems can arise with limits like $\frac{1}{a-b}$, where both $a$ and $b$ tend to *positive* infinity. In our case we have $\frac{1}{a+b}$, and $a+b$ will always tend to positive infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor at order $1$ after some transformation:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2} -\sqrt{\frac1x}=\frac{\sqrt{1+2x}-1}{\sqrt x}=\frac{1+x+o(x)-1}{\sqrt x}=\sqrt{x}+o(\sqrt x).$$